# Decreasing the size of listitem?

Tags: android, listview, font-size

I've listed something in one listview using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` It takes core listview.

And, i can't decrease the font size of their items. How can i decrease that? I've search the size element in XML files but, i've not found yet. Anyone know the answer for this? See my result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2BFB.png)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are adding the textViews in the listItem, you can control the font Size , with

```
android:textSize
```

**EDIT**

i see you are using a standard list item. then copy the `simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml` from android resources to your own custom xml, change the size attribute, and use it in the listAdapter.

you can get the resources from [here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/)

Comment: No, this is core listview. It need not any TextView.

Comment: yes, that mean android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice this is the core listview providing by android.R package. It need not any listview also. Just use this with adapter.

Comment: Where can i copy the resource?

Comment: Yes, its working fine. Thanks for your help. I didn't know about this type of method. And, also thanks for giving that link. Shall i use that link always?

Comment: Hey Yashwant, Can you please tell me how to do that, I have downloaded the file from the URL you have mentioned and paste it in the layout folder of my application, but I cannot see any effect happening. Where should I do that. Thanx for your help.